# So i have a 1978 elcamino with a 700r4 that im swapping to a 4l60e. Now i know that its computer controlled so would a eztcu take care of everything?

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, part-interchange

Need to know if I need anything other than the tci eztcu kit for this swap since the 700r4 doesn't run off a computer and the 4l60e does please help

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

If this is the kit you're getting, it **should include everything you need to *control* the 4L60e transmission**. Obviously, you're going to need expendables like transmission fluid. You're also going to need new connectors for the cooler, as I believe the 4L60e is different than the 700r4. You'll need to double check the yoke on the driveshaft to ensure it fits properly, as well as the length of the driveshaft may need to be shortened.

You can look at [this video](https://youtu.be/4V30Feg4hAQ?si=eW4gQ-fK6utPWs1V) to get a better understanding of the controller, what comes in the package, and installation.

[image]